# Error in connecting to Tomcat default page

Tags: android, android-emulator, tomcat7

I can connect to Apache server from Chrome and Firefox by typing 127.0.1.1:8080 and the default page is shown, but when I type the same from my Android emulator, no webpage is loaded, and I am shown a request timeout error, even if I try to connect via localhost .

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at localhost, what is wrong with my localhost?

I also tried 10.0.2.2 from the Android emulator, still can't connect, what is wrong here? Is my localhost switched? How can I fix it?

Please help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you left off the port number and it must be different port number that is not assigned to the emulator

so if Tomcat is on port 8080 than:

http:// 10.0.2.2:8080 /

the 127 IP number was instructing the emulator to connect to itself but you do not have super user access to the service at that address hence the timeout